# How do I reorder the dimensions of a rank 3 tensor in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensor, tensorflow.js

Suppose I have the following 2 tensors:

```js
var a = tf.tensor([[1,2],[3,4]]);
var b = tf.tensor([[5,6],[7,8]]);
```

I can stack them together like this:

```js
var c = tf.stack([a, b]);
```

By doing `c.print()`, I can see how Tensorflow has stacked the 2 tensors:

```
Tensor
    [[[1, 2],
      [3, 4]],

     [[5, 6],
      [7, 8]]]
```

However, I want to  stack them like so instead:

```
Tensor
    [[[1, 5],
      [2, 6]],
     [[3, 7],
      [4, 8]]]
```

In other words, if the dimensions of tensor `c` are `A, B, C`, how can I reorder the dimensions to be `B, C, A`?

I have tried reading the [Tensorflow.js API documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.7.0/), but from what I can see there isn't a way of doing this (unless I've missed it).

I have also tried implementing this with plain Javascript arrays, but I have noted that this is very inefficient and slow (code for this available upon request, I suspect it's because when handling multiple arrays ~3Kx2K it allocates a lot on the heap).

**How can I reorder the dimensions of a tensor from `A, B, C` to be `B, C, A`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two tensors can be stacked along the axis -1

```js
const a = tf.tensor([[1,2],[3,4]]);
const b = tf.tensor([[5,6],[7,8]]);
const c = tf.stack([a, b], axis=-1);
c.print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

To change the ordering of a tensor, `transpose` can be used and the way the axis are to be reordered can be given as parameter

```js
const a = tf.tensor([[1,2, 3],[3,4, 7]]);
const b = tf.tensor([[5,6, 20],[7,8, 10]]);
const c = tf.stack([a, b]); // default axis = 0
const d = c.transpose([1, 2, 0])
d.print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This does the trick. This is also the fastest answer out of the 2, so marking this as the answer. Ref https://asciinema.org/a/334061 (benchmark test code: https://ybin.me/p/75ed54ec96e9383e#IdZbnN+yz8YFTVTq9ECV9MLkJsf/5bOXX3C5vA3vpnA=).

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
var a = tf.tensor([[1,2],[3,4],[10,11]]);
var b = tf.tensor([[5,6],[7,8],[20,21]]);

x = a.transpose().stack(b.transpose()).transpose();
x.print();
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works like a charm, but unfortunately it's slower than the other answer, so I'm marking that one as the solution. But thanks anyway!